# Epad Sign Form on Netsuite

Tags: javascript, forms, netsuite

I dont have much coding experience, but we had this script developed a few years ago whereby we could sign invoices on Netsuite, sometime during 2016 it stopped working on chrome and firefox, presuming some function has been removed or changed in Chrome etc, as the script still works in IE.

Is there anyone that can maybe see why it would of stopped working, as it is a real pain using netsuite on IE, it is extremely slow loading and or processing any workflows or scripts we have running

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Filename: suit_epad_sign.js
// Version: 1.0
//
// Suitelet to sign an Invoice using an ePad
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function captureSignature(request, response)
{
var context = nlapiGetContext();    

if (request.getMethod() == 'GET' ) {
try {
    var caburl = context.getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_tris_activex_cab_url');

    // Find which browser is being used
    var isChrome = new Boolean(false);
    var agent = request.getHeader('User-Agent');
    if (agent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
        isChrome = true
    }

    var form = nlapiCreateForm('Sign Invoice');
    form.setScript('customscript_tric_epad_sign_inv_client');
    var uploaddone = request.getParameter('custparam_upd');     

    var invoiceid = request.getParameter('custparam_iid');
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord ('invoice', invoiceid);

    var invoiceidfield = form.addField('invoiceid','text', 'Invoice ID');
    invoiceidfield.setDisplayType ('hidden');
    invoiceidfield.setDefaultValue(invoiceid);

    var customerid = record.getFieldValue('entity');
    var isCashCompany = nlapiLookupField('customer', customerid, 'custentity_is_cash_company');
    var entity = '';
    if (isCashCompany == 'T') {
        var contactid = record.getFieldValue('custbody_invoice_contact');
        entity = nlapiLookupField('contact', contactid, 'custentity_cash_company', true);   
    } else {
        entity = record.getFieldText('entity');
    }

    var entityfield = form.addField('entity','text', 'Customer');
    entityfield.setDefaultValue(entity);
    entityfield.setDisplayType('disabled');
    entityfield.setLayoutType('normal', 'startcol');

    var contact = record.getFieldText('custbody_invoice_contact');
    var contactfield = form.addField('contact','text', 'Contact');
    contactfield.setDefaultValue(contact);
    contactfield.setDisplayType('disabled');
    contactfield.setLayoutType('normal', 'none');

    var invoiceno = record.getFieldValue('tranid');
    var invoicenofield = form.addField('invoiceno','text', 'Invoice Number');
    invoicenofield.setDefaultValue(invoiceno);
    invoicenofield.setDisplayType('disabled');
    invoicenofield.setLayoutType('normal', 'none');

    var total = record.getFieldValue('total');
    var totalfield = form.addField('total','text', 'Invoice Total');
    totalfield.setDefaultValue(total);
    totalfield.setDisplayType('disabled');
    totalfield.setLayoutType('normal', 'none');

    var affirmationfield = form.addField('affirmation','text', 'Affirmation');
    var affirmation = 'Contact: ' + contact + ' from company: ' + entity + '\n';
    affirmation += 'Invoice Number: ' + invoiceno + ' for amount: R' + total;
    affirmationfield.setDefaultValue(affirmation);
    affirmationfield.setDisplayType('hidden');

    if (isChrome == true) {
        // Chrome specific fields start
//  var chromesignfield = form.addField('chromesign','inlinehtml', 'Chrome Signature');
//  chromesignfield.setDefaultValue ('<input type="image" src="images/start.png" id="connect"/>');

        var chromesignimagefield = form.addField('chromesignimage','inlinehtml', 'Chrome Signature Image');
        chromesignimagefield.setLayoutType('normal', 'startcol');
        chromesignimagefield.setDefaultValue ('<img id="signImage" width="400" height="200" style="border:thin solid #696969;"/>');
//      chromesignimagefield.setDefaultValue ('<img id="signImage" src="images/signImage_400.png" width="400" height="200" style="border:thin solid #696969;"/>');

        var chromesignlabelfield = form.addField('chromesignlabel','inlinehtml', 'Chrome Signature Label');
        chromesignlabelfield.setDefaultValue ('<label id="lblError"></label>');

        // Chrome specific fields end       
    } else {

        // IE Specific fields
        var signaturefield = form.addField('signature','inlinehtml', 'Signature');
        signaturefield.setLayoutType('normal', 'startcol');
        var signobject = '<OBJECT id=esCapture1 classid=clsid:84C046A7-4370-4D91-8737-87C12F4C63C5 width="300" height="160" codebase="' + caburl + '" VIEWASTEXT>';
        signobject += '<param name="useslibrary" value="websignAx">';
        signobject += '<param name="useslibrarycodebase" value="websignax.cab">';
        signobject += '<param name="useslibraryversion" value="10,0,0,1">IntegriSign Signature Control';
        signobject += '</OBJECT>';

        signaturefield.setDefaultValue(signobject);

    }
    var jpegfield = form.addField('jpegcontents','inlinehtml', 'JPEG');
    jpegfield.setDefaultValue('<input type="hidden" name="jpegcontents">');     

    var printedfield = form.addField('printed','checkbox', 'Already Printed');
    printedfield.setDisplayType ('hidden');

    var timestampfield = form.addField('timestamp','text', 'Timestamp');
    timestampfield.setDisplayType ('hidden');

    var hashfield = form.addField('hash','longtext', 'Hash');
    hashfield.setDisplayType ('hidden');

    var host = request.getURL().substring(0, (request.getURL().indexOf('.com') + 4) );
    if (isChrome == true) {
        form.addButton('bb1GetSignature', 'Sign');
    } else {
        form.addButton('bb1GetSignature', 'Sign', 'signNow');       
    }
    form.addButton('capture', 'Save Signature', 'saveSignature');
    if (uploaddone == 'Y') {
        form.addButton('print', 'Print Invoice', "printInvoice('" + host + "','" + invoiceid + "')");       
    }

    response.writePage(form);

} catch (err) {
    var errMessage = err;
    if (err instanceof nlobjError) {
        errMessage = errMessage + ' ' + err.getDetails();
    } 
    nlapiLogExecution ('ERROR', 'Get Error', errMessage);       
    var errorhtml = '<html><body><h1>Get Error: ' + errMessage + '</h1></body></html>';
    response.write(errorhtml);
}
} else {
    // Post
try {

    var folderid = context.getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_tris_signature_folder');

    var jpegcontents = request.getParameter('jpegcontents');
    var invoiceid = request.getParameter('invoiceid');
    var invoiceno = request.getParameter('invoiceno');
    var timestamp = request.getParameter('timestamp');
    nlapiLogExecution ('DEBUG', 'invoiceid', invoiceid + ' invoiceno ' + invoiceno + ' timestamp ' + timestamp);    
    nlapiLogExecution ('DEBUG', 'jpegcontents', jpegcontents);  

    var filename = 'INV-' + invoiceno + '.jpg';
    var jpegfile = nlapiCreateFile(filename, 'JPGIMAGE', jpegcontents);
    jpegfile.setFolder(folderid);
    jpegfile.setIsOnline(true);
    var fileid = nlapiSubmitFile(jpegfile);

    // Attach the signature to the Invoice record
    nlapiAttachRecord('file', fileid, 'invoice', invoiceid);

    jpegfile = nlapiLoadFile(fileid);
    var host = request.getURL().substring(0, (request.getURL().indexOf('.com') + 4) );
    var url = host + jpegfile.getURL();
// var url = 'https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=6317&c=TSTDRV163439&h=ab7cf81a28cc968d297b';   
    // Store the signature hash on the invoice record
    var hash = request.getParameter('hash');
//  var record = nlapiLoadRecord ('invoice', invoiceid);
//  record.setFieldValue('custbody_tris_signature_hash', hash);
//  record.setFieldValue('custbody_tris_signature_file_url', url);
//  record.setFieldValue('custbody_tris_signature_time', timestamp);
//  nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
    var fields = new Array();
    var values = new Array();
    fields[0] = 'custbody_tris_signature_hash';
    values[0] = hash;
    fields[1] = 'custbody_tris_signature_file_url';
    values[1] = url;
    fields[2] = 'custbody_tris_signature_time';
    values[2] = timestamp;
    nlapiSubmitField('invoice', invoiceid, fields, values);

    var params=[];
    params['custparam_iid'] = invoiceid;
    params['custparam_upd'] = 'Y';

    // Redirect back to Get
    response.sendRedirect('SUITELET', context.getScriptId(), context.getDeploymentId(), null, params);

} catch (err) {
    var errMessage = err;
    if (err instanceof nlobjError) {
        errMessage = errMessage + ' ' + err.getDetails();
    } 
    nlapiLogExecution ('ERROR', 'Post Error', errMessage);  
    var errorhtml = '<html><body><h1>Post Error: ' + errMessage + '</h1></body></html>';
    response.write(errorhtml);
}
}
}
```